# How to disable auto-pause in Secret of Monkey Island: SE?

Tags: the-secret-of-monkey-island-se, monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se

Is there any way to disable the auto pause that takes you to the menu screen?

I play Secret of Monkey Island: SE in windowed mode.  Whenever I click on something outside the window, the game will automatically pause and go to the menu screen.  I have a dual monitor setup, and I want to play Monkey Island on one screen, and work on something else in the other without having to constantly pause and resume the game.

Edit:

I found a [helpful Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285406/detecting-an-application-focus-change-hooking-something-for-hwnd-changes) that may be of use in writing a Monkey Island Un-Pauser program.

Comment: Monkey Island 2 SE has the same behavior. I don't know if it's possible to change however.

Comment: @sippa Thank you for posting this as a comment instead of an answer.  Why are there so many answers on this site that begin with "I'm not familiar" or "I don't know" and "Maybe"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how message passing works in Windows, but there may be a way to prevent loss-of-focus messages from reaching the game with an external program.

If you need assistance with writing such a program, remember there's always [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)!

Comment: Yes!  This sounds very interesting.  I will look into it and let you know if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it seems the only way to solve this problem.  I've since beaten the game and am no longer really worried about it, but I didn't actually end up writing the monkey island un-pause program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same problem you are having, but you could try the solution found [here](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/adventure/thesecretofmonkeyislandspecialedition/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-50475695&pid=960378):

`Open Task Manager

find MISE.exe in the "processes" list.

Right click it and then click "Set Affinity..."

Uncheck the checkbox next to all CPU cores except for one (it doesn't matter which one you leave checked, as long as only one is checked).

Play Game!`

If this works, and you don't want to do this every time, more information can be found in the thread to edit the program and make this solution permanent (i would obviously test it first before doing that)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't the issue I'm talking about.  Instead of the game randomly pausing itself, I am the one causing it by clicking outside the game window.

Comment: is that a feature of the game?

Comment: Why would you ever need to pause an adventure game?  It is a bug.

Comment: In that case the multi processor thing could still be the issue behind it, you could test it (looks like a quick test) and see if it works is all im saying

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I did try it out before my first comment, and unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. They just made so that it goes to the menu when the game loses focus.